# Ruby: DEPRECATED: Use assert_nil if expecting nil. This will fail in Minitest 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am trying to run some test cases using **Minitest** in **Ruby**.

Here's the class that I am testing**:

```
# square_root.rb

class SquareRoot

  def square_root(value)
    return nil if value < 0
    Math.sqrt(value).round
  end
end
```

**Here's my test case**:

```
# square_root_test.rb

require 'minitest/autorun'

class SquareRootTest <Minitest::Test
  def test_that_square_root_of_9_is_3
    assert_equal 3, square_root(9)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_17_is_4
    assert_equal 4, square_root(17)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_24_is_5
    assert_equal 5, square_root(24)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_negative_number_is_nil
    assert_equal nil, square_root(-1)
  end
end
```

But when I run the command below to run the test:

```
ruby square_root_test.rb
```

I get the deprecation warning below:

```
Run options: --seed 50741

# Running:

DEPRECATED: Use assert_nil if expecting nil from square_root_test.rb:26. This will
fail in Minitest 6.
....

Finished in 0.000839s, 4769.9228 runs/s, 4769.9228 assertions/s.
4 runs, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Following the message from the deprecation warning, I simply replaced the assertion:

```
assert_equal nil, square_root(-1)
```

with

```
assert_nil square_root(-1)
```

OR

```
assert_nil(square_root(-1))
```

So my test file looked like this afterwards:

```
# square_root_test.rb

require 'minitest/autorun'

class SquareRootTest <Minitest::Test
  def test_that_square_root_of_9_is_3
    assert_equal 3, square_root(9)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_17_is_4
    assert_equal 4, square_root(17)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_24_is_5
    assert_equal 5, square_root(24)
  end

  def test_that_square_root_of_negative_number_is_nil
    assert_nil square_root(-1)
  end
end
```

**Note**: That the comma `,` punctuation mark was removed as well.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: All other three tests for `assert_equal` are structurally identical and the rounding behaviour is irrelevant here. Maybe remove two of them for the sake of brevity?

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right. I am trying out some edge cases with it.

Comment: By all means, keep them in your code. What I meant is they don't add much value in the context of this Q/A.